# Как остановить таймер?

Tags: java, android

```
static Timer timer = new Timer();

//поместил запуск таймера в такой метод
void Timer(){    
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            time++;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimerView.setText("");
                    TimerView.setText(TimerView.getText() + " " + time);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

}

Есть вот такой таймер, который выводит в `TextView` числа равные пройденным секундам, т.е. каждую сек. обновляет TextView и пишет число равное пойденной секунде.

Вопрос 1. Как остановить таймер, например, через 15 сек. И если таймер не остановить и он досчитал до 15 сек, значит что-то выполняется. Куда мне в этот код записать, то что должно выполнятся.

Вопрос 2. Как остановить таймер через обработчик нажатий. Например на 7-й секунде нажал кнопку, то что должен выполнить таймер после 15 сек он уже не выполнит, а выполняется другая команда и таймер вновь начал заново отсчитывать. и т.д. Как останавливать я понял - timer.cancel(); но как вновь его запустить что бы он начал заново считать секунды. В методе onCreate я запускаю командой Timer();, но когда пишу эту команду в обработчик нажатия, то приложение выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В вашем коде этот вызов:

   ```or-tag
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
   ```

   Назначает запуск таймера каждую 1 секунду(=1000 миллисекунд; третий аргумент функции), с первым запуском через 1 секунду(второй аргумент).

   Если вам не нужно постоянно повторять задачу - уберите третий аргумент, а в качестве второго укажите нужное вам время(здесь - 15 секунд):

   ```or-tag
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 15000);
   ```

   Если нужно - сделайте 2-й и 3-й параметр равным нужному вам времени:

   ```or-tag
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 15000, 15000);
   ```
2. Используйте в обработчике нажатия кнопки вызов:

   ```or-tag
   timer.cancel();
   ```

   Он отменит назначенный таймер. При необходимости, вы можете после этого заново назначить запуск таймера.

Comment: я поместил таймер в одельнный метод

Comment: а какой командой вновь его запустить??

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра, только заново запланировав его выполнение через методы scheduleAtFixedRate() или schedule(). Паузу/возобновление таймер к сожалению не реализует - только планирование и отмену. Оставшееся после отмены время, к сожалению тоже не узнать - оно скрыто от пользователя.

Comment: всем спасибо огромное - разобрался